# Always have an empty TableRow at the bottom of the TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablerow

I have a `TableView` where I add a new row by right clicking on the row below where I want to place the row and choosing "add" in a context menu. This becomes a problem when the `TableView` has so many rows that the entire view is filled with filled rows, since no empty rows are displayed. When this happens, I can only add a row above the row at the bottom, but not below it.

Adding a "dummy item" to the bottom of the `TableView` when that is used is not an option. I need to add a `TableRow` that has a item that is null, like the rows that usually fill out the viewport of the TableView when there's not enough items to fill the viewport.

Is there a way to make sure that there's always a `TableRow` with no item at the bottom of the table?

Edit: Adding a context menu to the entire `TableView` and automatically add row at the bottom when that is used is not an option either. This is because I need to add a style class to the row below the input index to provide the user with feedback on where the row will be placed. Therefore there needs to be a `TableRow` object to add the style class to.

**Edit:** I realize my text was a little bit messy. Here's an attempt at clarifying the actual behaviour I want:

I don't want the viewport to always display an empty row at the bottom, which would be some kind of "sticky row" behaviour. I want the actual table to display an empty row after the last row. I.e: When I'm in the "middle" of the list, and can't see the last row, no empty row should be displayed. The only time the empty row is needed is when I want to add an item at the end of the table list. Therefore when I scroll down so I see the end of the list, that's when I need an empty row. The reason I need this exact behaviour is explained in the original text.

Comment: Not that it really helps, but there is an [RFE for it](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090435) (Item 3). Maybe it will be implemented in a future version...

Comment: Can you clarify the actual behavior if the table has more rows than it can show? You still want one blank row visible at the bottom, even though there are rows scrolled out of view beyond that blank row? That seems a bit counter-intuitive for the user. I usually just have "add above" and "add below" menu items for this kind of functionality (similar e.g. to a table in some word-processing software).

Comment: I've added a clarification of the desired behaviour. The problem is not when the table has more rows than it can show, it's when the table is full (the difference between those two is only one row, but oh well). I do not "want one blank row visible atat the bottom, even though there are rows scrolled out of view beyond that blank row". Sorry for the messy question.